# Debugging standalone Typescript file in React project using VScode

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, create-react-app

I've a React project created using [create react app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app). Sometimes I want to play with typescript code in a separate file and debug it.

VSCode requires the generated .js folder to be set in the debug configuration, otherwise the following message appears.

```
Cannot launch program 'File.ts' setting the 'outFiles' attribute might help.
```

Or if set to "outFiles": ["${fileDirname}/*.js"]:

```
Cannot launch program 'File.ts' because corresponding JavaScript cannot be found.
```

I can't find where the project is generating the .js files. It seems create react app uses webpack, which should use [ts-loader](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader). It generates a bundle.js file, but I can't even find it in the workspace folder either.

For reference, my full launch.json. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
{
   "version": "0.2.0",
   "configurations": [   
      // Not working  
      {
         "type": "node",
         "request": "launch",
         "name": "Debug File",
         "program": "${file}",
         "outFiles": ["${fileDirname}/*.js"]
      },
      {
         "type": "node",
         "name": "Run tests",
         "request": "launch",
         "args": [
            "test",
            "--runInBand"
         ],
         "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
         "console": "integratedTerminal",
         "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
         "disableOptimisticBPs": true,
         "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/react-scripts",
         "protocol": "inspector"
      },
      {
         "name": "Chrome",
         "type": "chrome",
         "request": "launch",
         "url": "http://localhost:3000",
         "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/src"
     }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Do you have a Typescript.json file?

Comment: If it is a "standalone" ts file launched separately with node, what role does the CRA/webpack build play anyway? The former is node debugging, the latter is client side debugging.

Comment: I have a tsconfig.json, which can be found here. This was created automatically by create react app: https://gist.github.com/ricardoekm/e69bc615d95903d86b95c95571f00bba. About Webpack my guess is that it's loading the typescript files directly from my source folder, instead of letting ts compiler to compile them and then load it. This adds hot reload capability.

Answer (score 0):

You can either build the project as a .ts project and support the legacy js files, or you can include the typescript files output folder so you compile the .ts into .js, and the .js module will be included in your  React app. 
But you cannot just drop a ts file in a js project and expect React to make that connection for you.

To keep your workspace organized, I recommend move the ts to a separate folder, init that folder as a ts project and include it back in your React project as a library (even if it's a single file)

You can then use testing frameworks such as `mocha + chai` and `jest` to test it. Both mocha and jest can test your .ts directly without requiring your to compile it (they're doing it for you, using packages such as `jest-ts`)

`Lerna` or `Yarn workspaces` can help with the linkage, and vs-code can be easily configured to support multiple projects (packages) in the workspace. including for testing.

Comment: Sorry if my original question wasn't clear. I've created using react app with typescript template (https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-typescript/). All my source code is typescript, however I can't figure out how to run a single file.